# Multiple git subtree of same repo

Tags: git, git-subtree

In a repo called `apps` I'm stuck with using a folder structure like

```
/apps
 - /app1
   - /shared
 - /app2
   - /shared
 - /app3
   - /shared
```

where `shared` is a separate repo. How do I use git subtree such that changes to any `app1/shared`, `app2/shared`, `app3/shared` take effect in each other and can be pushed back to the `shared` repo?

Comment: Does that have to be done using `git subtree`? Seems like an ideal candidate for a symlink.

Comment: @PaulHicks Our constraint is that the `/shared` folders have to exist and be editable in all of those places. Can symlink do that?

Comment: symlinks work with `git submodule`: I admit to not having tried `git subtree`, but I'd try it and see. Set up your subtree in app1, then create symlinks in app2 and app3 to app1/shared. Hopefully it'll work and you can provide an answer to your own question :)